# "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" warning while trying to set dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was just trying to do a simple value modification operation in pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y = x * 2
z = [-1,-2,-3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y','z'])
df['x'] = x
df['y'] = y
df['z'] = z

for i in range(len(df['z'])):
    if df['z'].iloc[i] < 0:
        df['x'].iloc[i] *= -1
        df['y'].iloc[i] *= -1
        df['z'].iloc[i] *= -1
```

However it warned: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
I was not aware how chained assignments were used in this case.

It gave me right answer but significantly slower though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performace if loops is slowier, so the best is avoid it and use vectorized pandas function if possible.

I think you can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and if condition is `True` multiple by `-1`:

```
df = df.mask(df['z'] < 0, df.mul(-1))
print (df)
      x     y   z
0  -1.0  -2.0   1
1  -2.0  -4.0   2
2  -3.0  -6.0   3
3   4.0   8.0   4
4   5.0  10.0   5
5   6.0  12.0   6
6   7.0  14.0   7
7   8.0  16.0   8
8   9.0  18.0   9
9  10.0  20.0  10
```

Another solution is select by condition and multiple by `-1`:

```
df.loc[df['z'] < 0] *= -1
print (df)
      x     y   z
0  -1.0  -2.0   1
1  -2.0  -4.0   2
2  -3.0  -6.0   3
3   4.0   8.0   4
4   5.0  10.0   5
5   6.0  12.0   6
6   7.0  14.0   7
7   8.0  16.0   8
8   9.0  18.0   9
9  10.0  20.0  10
```